# Path too long exception in MTM

Tags: visual-studio-2017, coded-ui-tests, mtm

**Trying to run CodedUI test cases using MTM:**
**Several errors:**

Test Run deployment issue: Failed to access the file 'C:\Users\master\AppData\Local\VSEQT\QTController\rm\1234\master_TestController 2017-07-28 08_10_50\Out\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\Architecture Tools\Providers\AssemblyMetadata\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ArchitectureTools.AssemblyMetadataProvider.dll': **System.IO.PathTooLongException**: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.'."

Comment: I had a simillar when i tried to clone a respository, my solution was to clone it onto the root of C:\, Try changing the path if you can.

Comment: Cannot change the path. It is auto-generated.

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest way to solve the **PathTooLongException** is tweaking the path space.

The test result in the test control is using the folder `...\VSEQT\QTController\rm\[run ID]\[name] [date]\..\...` to store files before attaching them to TFS. This location's length is usually very long.

So users must handle the attachments' name to avoid long path exception. Or changing that default location. A solution is changing the `QTController.exe.config` "*WorkingDirectory*" in `QTController.exe.config` and make the path shorter.